# File.readallbytes not finding Image file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have checked many answers regarding this and nothing could help me. My Scenario is I have a table which has a column to add image as byte array. I declared the model property as array to store image bytes. Then in migrations configuration class i am seeding data to my table which includes an image.

```
 var gembymonth = new List<GemStoneByMonth>{
             new GemStoneByMonth
            {
                EnglishZodiac="Aries",
                SanskritZodiac = "Mesa",
                GemEng="Garnet",               

                GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/GarnetGem.png")
 }
```

the file path i provided here is for my local system and it works well. If i give any other type of path it throws an error.If i add ~/content/"filename" as my image is in my content folder and when i host it to my server it returns obvious error "Could not find a part of the path". I have tried many methods like

Server.MapPath
but server.path says it does  not contain a definition and when i resolve i get system.sql namespace then mappath shoes error.

my model class

```
    public class GemStoneByMonth
    {

        public int GemStoneByMonthId { get; set; }
        public string EnglishZodiac { get; set; }
        public string MalayalamZodiac { get; set; }
        public string SanskritZodiac { get; set; }
        public string GemEng { get; set; }
        public string GemMal { get; set; }
        public byte[] GemImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Migration Configuration seed method

```
 protected override void Seed(Astrology.AstroDatabase.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            var gembymonth = new List<GemStoneByMonth>{
             new GemStoneByMonth
            {
                EnglishZodiac="Aries",                  
                SanskritZodiac = "Mesa",
                GemEng="Garnet",                                   
                GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/GarnetGem.png")
            //    GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/GarnetGem.png")
            },

             new GemStoneByMonth
            {
                EnglishZodiac = "Taurus",              
                SanskritZodiac = "Vrsabha",
                GemEng = "Lapis Lazuli",                
                GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/LapisLazuli.png")

            },

             new GemStoneByMonth
            {
                EnglishZodiac = "Gemini",                ,
                SanskritZodiac = "Mithuna",
                GemEng = "Aquamarine",                
                GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/Aquamarine.png")
            },

             new GemStoneByMonth
            {
                EnglishZodiac = "Cancer",                  
                SanskritZodiac = "Karka",
                GemEng = "Yellow Saphire",                  
                GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/Yellow Saphire.png")
            },

            new GemStoneByMonth
            {
                EnglishZodiac = "Leo",                 
                SanskritZodiac = "Siṃha",
                GemEng = "Red Coral",                
                GemImage = File.ReadAllBytes("E:/NavBar/Astrology/Astrology/Astrology/Content/Images/Redcoral.png")

            },

};

            gembymonth.ForEach(p => context.GemStoneByMonths.AddOrUpdate(s => new { s.EnglishZodiac, s.SanskritZodiac, s.GemEng, s.GemImage }, p));

        }
        }
```

I have used this filepath because none of the rest works. and i know obviously its not gonna work in server as its my local file path.

I am scratching my head for hours on this. Can someone say how to map my files properly as i am hosting my site to server. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: So the file doesn't exist at that location on the server.

Comment: post the code you are really using, including server.mappath and all, and the complete exception with call stack. probably the path that exists on your local system just isn't there on the server. a server.mappath approach sounds like the right thing to do in this case, especially when you're using it with relative paths without a fixed drive letter and root directory. file system paths should be using backslashes instead of forward slashes, although modern OS will understand both and I don't think this is the problem here.

Comment: but when i use  server.mappath it throws error. It doesnt contain a definition,

Comment: `Server.MapPath` accepts a virtual (internet address) path, not a physical file path. it translates it. what If you stored only the file names (without any path information) in the database and build the absolute path at runtime?

Comment: I have updated my question. i added images to content folder and trying to add it from there. after when i populate db i will delete those images. how can i add file name. can you say?

Comment: sorry I thought I'd get it but now I don't. So your goal is to load the images from database at runtime, and not have the files on the server at all? then you'll have to stream the content of the database colum that contains the picture as the http response, or save to disk on request and serve that to the clients. but then what is the question? how not to lose the original file name => add a string member to `GemStoneByMonth` class. are you going to seed the database on the production server or starting with a database on that server that is already seeded?

Comment: The images in my images folder is there on server. What i want is i want to seed that images as bytes to my byte column. when it populate my table using those images.. then i can remove those images right? As I have got the binary data. thats my point,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153062/discussion-between-abhijith-and-dlatikay).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use either `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` or `Server.MapPath`.

For example,

```
string path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\Content\\Images\\";
// Or string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
var gembymonth = new List<GemStoneByMonth>
{
    new GemStoneByMonth
    {
        EnglishZodiac = "Cancer",
        SanskritZodiac = "Karka",
        GemEng = "Yellow Saphire",
        GemImage = path + "Yellow Saphire.png"
    }
};
```

Comment: let me check this one